# Download pdf file using python3

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, download

*I want to download this website 's pdf file using python3 https://qingarchives.npm.edu.tw/index.php?act=Display/image/207469Zh18QEz#74l*

Comment: That is not a PDF URL but an URL to some document viewing component which might internally use some pdf. If that component is designed for not sharing the pdf and is properly implemented, you cannot download the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This might accomplish what you're trying to achieve:

```py
import requests

# URL to be downloaded
url = "https://cfm.ehu.es/ricardo/docs/python/Learning_Python.pdf"


def download_pdf(url, file_name):
    # Send GET request
    response = requests.get(url)
    # Save the PDF
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)


download_pdf(url, 'myDownloadedFile.pdf')
```

Comment: This method is not downloadable

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib import request

response = request.urlretrieve("https://cfm.ehu.es/ricardo/docs/python/Learning_Python.pdf", "learing_python.pdf")
```

or

```
import wget

URL = "https://cfm.ehu.es/ricardo/docs/python/Learning_Python.pdf"

response = wget.download(URL, ".learing_python.pdf")
```